# How can I prevent Firefox from accessing files outside of its .config directory?

Tags: firefox, security

[A vulnerability in Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/08/06/firefox-exploit-found-in-the-wild/) was disclosed today that allows an attacker to execute JavaScript in a "local file context", giving them access to the file system. In the wild, this was used to scan the home directory for files containing credentials and uploading them to a remote server.

In my opinion, the web browser has no business accessing *any* file on my file system except those it strictly needs to function (which should be its `.config` subdirectory, the `Downloads` folder (write only) and possibly a temp folder). How can I enforce that?

Comment: `All Firefox users are urged to update to Firefox 39.0.3. The fix has also been shipped in Firefox ESR 38.1.1.` From the link you provided, posted 6/9, not saying this is the answer to the question, but, would be good to mention at least.

Comment: Try [apparmor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor), though I doubt it works according to one's opinions. A quick look through /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox shows quite a bit more permissive profile that you'd hope for.

Comment: Is there a concrete reason to not upgrade? Otherwise as mark kirby said upgrading is the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also:

- Use firejail to create sandbox for firefox
- Create LXC (built in kernel VM) container to keep firefox in jail
- Add firefox to AppArmor (built-in kernel security module).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your system. A patched Firefox version (39.0.3+build2-0ubuntu) is available for all Ubuntu releases.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade firefox
```

Comment: @kos Good point, changed :)

Comment: you should remove above comment and then ping me so that I will remove mine as well as it looks like you're hearing voices that aren't there!